# Select children objects using foreign key in django query

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-key-relationship

I have two models and i need to select fields from both models in a single query.

```
class Machines(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class AssignedUsers(model.Model):
    machine_id = models.ForeignKey(Machines, null=True)
    user_email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

i want to select all fields in Machines and user_email from AssignedUsers in my resultset.
What would be the most appropriate way to populate this queryset. so that it may help me on querying the resultset as follows.

```
q = Q()
q = Q(name__icontains=searchword) | Q(user_email__icontains=searchword)
filtered_list = result_set.filter(q)
```

Comment: Seems you need to follow the reverse key defined here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward, `rs.assignedusers_set`

Answer (score 0):

Note the `distinct()` method.  `Machines` can contain more than one matching `AssignedUsers` so `distinct()` will remove duplicates from queryset.

```
machines = Machines.objects \
                   .distinct() \
                   .filter(Q(name__icontains=searchword) |
                           Q(assignedusers__user_email__icontains=searchword))
```